# Does there exist two different fields over $F$ such that they have the same intermediate fields?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Suppose $K_1$ and $K_2$ are two different field extesnions over field $F$, and all the proper intermediate fields in the field extension $K_1$ of $F$ and $K_2$ of $F$ are the same.(here we suppose both of the field extensions have more than $1$ intermidiate field, i.e.  $F$ is not the only intermediate field of the extensions above), can we find such fields $K_1,K_2$ and $F$?

Comment: You only ask "can we find such fields?", so only one example, not in general.

Comment: Yes, I meant both $C_4$, as in the answer you have accepted, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $F=\Bbb Q$, $K_1=\Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]{2})$ and $K_2=\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}})$. In both cases, the only intermediate field is $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2})$. (Besides $\Bbb Q$, of course)

Answer (score 0):

Sure; just take any field extension $F\subset K$ that has no intermediate extension, and then extend this in two different ways to $K\subset K_1,K_2$, again both with no intermediate extensions.

Comment: this doesn't always work. If we take, for example $F=\Bbb Q$, $K=\Bbb Q(i)$ and $K_1=\Bbb Q(i,\sqrt{2})$, $K_2=\Bbb Q(i,\sqrt{3})$, then $K_1 / F$ and $K_2/F$ have more than just $K$ as intermediate extensions

Comment: @LukasHeger You are right; some more conditions are required and it gets a bit ugly. An easy way out would be to require all extension to be finite and with pairwise coprime degrees. But a concrete example like in your answer is better (+1)